# Por que una tabla no se crea completa?

Tags: html, html5, css

Pregunta orientada a `HTML` y `CSS`.

En el momento estoy creando una tabla por medio de un `SELECT` de una BD , Sin embargo he notado que la tabla no se crea completa, y aunque no salta una excepción la página queda incompleta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con el style   `"<div style='overflow:auto'>"`

Y funciona vertical ...pero no horizontal.... que debo corregir ??

Esta etiqueta la probé harcodeada en el código no en la hoja de stilo css.

```
ResultSet lista = (ResultSet)request.getAttribute( "lista" );
if(lista != null)
{
    if( lista.first())
    {
        lista.beforeFirst();
        out.println("<form method='post' action=''>"
            + "<div style='overflow:auto'>"       
            + "<table border ='2px' align='center' id='tableedit' >"
            + "<caption align='center'> OFICINAS EN BD </caption>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<th>NOMBRE OFICINA</th>"
            + "<th>ZONA</th>" 
            + "<th>CIUDAD</th>"        
            + "<th>EDITAR</th>"
            + "<th>ELIMINAR</th>"
            + "</tr>");

        while( lista.next( ) )
        {
            //Modificamos el ID de la zona por el nombre para la vista
            String z = lista.getString( 3 );
            String nz = "";
            if (!z.equals(""))
            {
                ResultSet droplst3 = s.consultarZonas( 1 , z );
                droplst3.first();//Primera coincidencia
                nz = droplst3.getString( 2 );
                droplst3.close();
            }

            //Modificamos el ID de la ciudad por el nombre para la vista
            String ciudad = lista.getString( 4 );                                                                                  
            String nc = "";

            if(!ciudad.equals(""))
            {
                String c = ciudad;   
                ResultSet droplst4 = s.consultarCiudades( 1 , c );
                droplst4.first();//Primera coincidencia
                nc = droplst4.getString( 2 );
                droplst4.close();
            }

            out.println("<tr>"
              + "<td >" + lista.getString( 2 ) + "</td>" 
              + "<td  id='editable'>" + nz + "</td>"
              + "<td  id='editable'>" + nc + "</td>"        
              + "<td><a href='editarOficina.jsp?IdO="+ lista.getInt( 1 ) +" &nomO="+ lista.getString( 2 ) +" &IdZ="+ lista.getString( 3 ) +"&IdC="+ lista.getString( 4 ) +"'>"
                      + "<img src='IMG/editarCampo.png' width='25' height='25'></td>"
              + "<td><a href='eliminarOficina.jsp?IdO="+ lista.getInt( 1 ) +" &nomO="+ lista.getString( 2 ) +" &IdZ="+ lista.getString( 3 ) +"&IdC="+ lista.getString( 4 ) +"'>"
                      + "<img src='IMG/eliminarCampo.png' width='25' height='25'></td>"         
              + "</tr>"); 
        }   
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</form>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Te sugiero cerrar los tag A; y finalizar los IMG (<img .... />); el TR que tiene TH colocarlo dentro del THEAD; por consiguiente usar el TBODY.

Comment: Así es, principalmente es porque abres etiquetas <a> pero nunca las cierras. Lo de las tablas igual el navegador se apiada de ti y las interpreta, pero igual hay que tratar de hacer lo que menciona Roberto con las tablas.

Comment: Vas añadiendo código sobre la marcha, y es posible que el motor DOM del navegador te lo corrija, ya que en el DOM de la página nunca pueden haber elementos incorrectos. Esto significa que si añades un `<table>` con dos o tres `<tr>` pero no cierras con `</table>`, **el navegador lo hará por ti**. Lo que añadas después estará fuera de una tabla, ya que sigues añadiendo `<tr>`s sin `<table>`. Para corregirlo, añade todo a una cadena de texto (o incluso mejor a un array y luego le haces un _join_) y lo escribes en `out` todo de golpe al final.